# Angular animation wont display changes until I mouse over component

Tags: angular, svg, angular-animations

I am applying an opacity fade, between 0 and 1, to some iframes. The iframes are in an svg by using foreignObject. It starts with state 0. Once animated to 1, you can only see the iframes after I mouse over any component with mouse event handling. After the state is at 1, you can clearly see the state change 1 -> 0 has no issues in comparison with 0 -> 1.

No errors are in the console during this animation.

I need help from you to find out why the 0 -> 1 state does not animate smoothly.

Here is the component:

**musicpage.component.ts**

```
  private animatecontentfade(state: number) {
    let params: any = {}
    params[inputopacityname] = state

    let animation = this.animator.create(this.castcontent, {
      params: params
    })

    animation.onDone(() => {
      this.changer.markForCheck()
    })

    animation.play()
  }
```

**musicpage.component.html**

```
<svg>
    <g class="content-page" #content>
        <g class="scroll-box">
            <g class="scroll-item">
                <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
                        <xhtml:iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"
                            class="music-player"
                            src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/689363290&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true">
                        </xhtml:iframe>
                </foreignObject>                
            </g>

            <g class="scroll-item">
                <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%" y="230px">
                    <xhtml:iframe width="100%" frameborder="no"
                        class="music-player"                        
                        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/689387281&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true">
                    </xhtml:iframe>
                </foreignObject>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>

    <g app-scrollview class="scroll-view" (scrollbuttonmoved)="onscroll($event)"></g>
</svg>
```

**fadeout.ts (the animation)**

```
export const togglefade = animation(
    animate(
        '3s',
        style({
            opacity: `{{ ${inputopacityname} }}`
        })
    )
)
```

Comment: could you please provide stackblitz or codepen ?